# Create re-distributable image from a Virtual Machine

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have a VM in VirtualBox which i built up in the hope i can re-use the base image across multiple (17) machines without having to download install all the updates/programs etc etc 17 times. Does anyone know of a way to take this Virtual Disk and make it, installable? Or just a way to get the image across multiple machines?

Thanks

Comment: Saying what OS would help a lot. Without this, it would be pretty much impossible to answer this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I'm right your problem is not with "publishing" the image you created (as thatquestion is answered [here](https://superuser.com/questions/464445/how-to-reuse-virtualbox-disk-snapshots)) but insetad that windows updates get downloaded and installed on all instances all the time.
You could avoid this by "publishing" the image after it is up to date, or if you don't want that use [WSUS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/bb332157.aspx).
Still have to install X times all the updates but you need to download them just one time.

Comment: My problem is some how using the VM and creating something i can re-use across all the machines.
How/What to create from the VM?
How to restore?

I've made a system image from the windows 8 backup and its now restoring onto two machines. I think this is probably the best option?

Comment: In this case the answer on this link: http://superuser.com/questions/464445/how-to-reuse-virtualbox-disk-snapshots is just OK for you. Read the accepted answer (same applies to Windown, don't get confused by it being ubuntu)